# Define function inside a structure with defstruct

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Is it possible to define one of the slots of a structure like a function and access the slot to use the function? If it is, how can use it? For example, something like this:

```
(defstruct problem
   state
   (player (defun getplayer (some-state) (findplayer 1 some-state))) 
   (points (defun getpoints (some-state someplayer) (findpoints someplayer some-state)))
 )
```

Comment: No, you can't do this. I think you may want to look at CLOS, where you can define methods to access slots.

Comment: What is the intended semantics of what you wrote?  What are the arguments to `getplayer` and `getpoints` supposed to be?

Comment: This would probably depend on what exactly are you trying to achieve. You could put an actual function into `initform` of the slot (this would cause it to be created every time the struct is instantiated. You could specialize the function on the struct. You could also use classes, in which case you could also create funcallable classes and thus apply all OO mechanics to functions themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use one of two techniques:

The first would be to, instead of storing a function in the slot, store the symbol that names the function. Note this asumes the named functions to be defined elsewhere, outside of the structure def itself.

```
(Defstruct problem
  State
 (Points 'getpoints)
 (Player 'getplayer))
```

This may be used in a manner similar to:

```
 (Defvar p (make-problem ...))
 (Funcall (problem-points p) x)
 (Funcall (problem-player p) x y)
```

The reason this works is because, when provided a symbol, Funcall automatically resolves its fdefinition before invocation.  A second approach is very similar but instead of the symbol representing a named function, the slot is set directly to an anonymous function (called a "lambda expression").  This approach bears an additional similarity to the example you listed, I'm that the function assigned to a slot-value is defined within the definition or instantiation of the structure and does not rely on that function having been defined elsewhere. So:

```
(Defstruct problem
  State
 (Points (lambda (arg0) (some-computation arg0)))
 (Player (lambda (arg0 arg1) (other-computation arg0 arg1))))
```

And then:

```
 (Defvar q (make-problem ...))
 (Funcall (problem-points q) x)
 (Funcall (problem-player q) x y)
```

Hope that is helpful!

Comment: Thank you! It was this I wanted to know! Thank you again for your answer! ;)

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote won't work, but you can do this:

```
(defstruct problem () state)
(defgeneric getplayer (problem)
  (:method ((p problem))
    (find-player 1 (problem-state p))))
(defgeneric getpoints (problem player)
  (:method ((p problem) player)
    (findpoints player (problem-state p))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's also something nifty you could do:

```
(defclass get-player ()
  ((state :initarg :state :accessor state-of))
  (:metaclass sb-mop:funcallable-standard-class))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((this get-player) &rest initargs)
  (declare (ignore initargs))
  (sb-mop:set-funcallable-instance-function
   this (lambda ()
          (format t "~&I am: ~s, my state is: ~s" this (state-of this)))))

(let ((get-player (make-instance 'get-player :state :initial-state)))
  (funcall get-player)
  (setf (state-of get-player) :advanced-state)
  (funcall get-player))

;; I am: #<GET-PLAYER {10036104BB}>, my state is: :INITIAL-STATE
;; I am: #<GET-PLAYER {10036104BB}>, my state is: :ADVANCED-STATE
```

That is, you could have function objects, where you take control over the variables they captured. So, since you don't really need an instance of `problem` in your example code to invoke `getplayer` (you only need the `state`), then this approach could be interesting.